# Geocoder not putting out Address

Tags: android, list, geocoding

I have trouble shot it down to the Geocoder not putting out an address, but I do not know why.

```
public void button_address (View v){
//Create Geocoder
gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
//The string pulled from the app to be used  in the Geocoder
String loc = address.getText().toString();
//The list the Geocoder will fill
List<Address> add;
//Check to make sure there is a value in loc
Log.d(TAG, loc);
Log.d(TAG, "Before try/catch");
try {
    //Request Gecoder return string loc with an address for add
    add = gc.getFromLocationName(loc, 1);
    add.isEmpty();
    //Check to see if add is empty
    if(add.isEmpty()){ Log.d(TAG, "ADD is empty"); }

    double lat = add.get(0).getLatitude();
    double lon = add.get(0).getLongitude();
    Log.d(TAG, "lat:" + lat + ", long:" + lon);

} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please Try Entering Another Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Now here is my logcat

```
05-24 19:33:21.309: D/MainActivity(32508): 3111 world Dr, lake Buena vista, fl 32830
05-24 19:33:21.309: D/MainActivity(32508): Before try/catch
05-24 19:33:21.329: D/MainActivity(32508): ADD is empty
05-24 19:33:21.329: D/AndroidRuntime(32508): Shutting down VM
05-24 19:33:21.329: W/dalvikvm(32508): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    ... 11 more
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
05-24 19:33:21.418: E/AndroidRuntime(32508):    ... 14 more
05-24 19:33:23.839: I/Process(32508): Sending signal. PID: 32508 SIG: 9
```

So based on the fact that add returns empty and then in the logcat I get: IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 
I am sure that somehow the Geocoder is failing. I have internet permissions in the manifest, and checked to make sure that internet is working on the emulator through a web browser.

Hopefully some one else can see a simple problem that I have missed or has a recommendation. Thanks in advance for all you help.

Comment: you arraylist add is empty. this gc.getFromLocationName(loc, 1) is returning null

Comment: I am not sure why it is empty though.

Comment: cross check your location loc once

Comment: I had it print to the Logcat to insure it was looking good, the address I used was 3111 world Dr, lake Buena vista, fl 32830. I just try setting the string directly to that. The I thought maybe it has to do with the Locale setting. (I am currently in Japan and that address would probably not be found here). That did not create and items for the list either.

Comment: Thanks for you help, at first I thought it was my code, but I think it might be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for isEmpty but still trying to get the element from the list in next line.

```
try {
    //Request Gecoder return string loc with an address for add
    add = gc.getFromLocationName(loc, 1);
    add.isEmpty();
    //Check to see if add is empty
    if(add.isEmpty()){ Log.d(TAG, "ADD is empty"); }
    else {
    double lat = add.get(0).getLatitude();
    double lon = add.get(0).getLongitude();
    Log.d(TAG, "lat:" + lat + ", long:" + lon);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please Try Entering Another Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: Yes, I was getting errors that I concluded came from the fact I was trying the get data from the element. That is why I checked to see if it was empty. I now know that it is empty, but do not know why the Geocoder is not working.

Comment: I misunderstood your answer at first, that does look like a good way to run it, but I am still trying to figure out why it comes up empty.

Comment: As the document of Gecoder says `a list of Address objects. Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.` Check whether u have a network connectivity or restart the devices.

Comment: Thanks. I have looked into it more and it sounds like the Geocoder class might have some issues. I originally thought it might be my code since I am fairly new to programming.