# How to prevent app from closing when Geocoder address list is null?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to handle errors for my application that uses Geocoder, but whenever i try to get
the coordinates of a non-existent location my app crashes. I know this has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733270/geocoder-not-putting-out-address)
but i don't think it was resolved. Anyway i can prevent it from force closing, and just notify the user to input a correct string?

Here is my code. a Sample string would be "qwihedhladhaw"

```
getCoordinatesFromString("qwihedhladhaw");

    public double[] getCoordinatesFromString (String location) {
    Utils util = new Utils();
    double coordinates[] = {0.0, 0.0};
    if(util.checkIfEmptyString(location)) {
        this.canGetCoordinates = false;
        System.out.println("EMPTY STRINGS");
    } else {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);

        //geocoding
        List<Address> addressList;
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1, 14.479894, 120.970062, 14.774883, 121.061676 );
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            System.out.println(address);
            if(address.hasLatitude() && address.hasLongitude()){
                coordinates[0] = address.getLatitude();
                coordinates[1] = address.getLongitude();
                this.canGetCoordinates = true;
                this.isLocationValid = true;
                System.out.println(coordinates[0]);
                System.out.println(coordinates[1]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    return coordinates;
}
```

Output logs are:

```
    {07-30 23:12:50.291: I/System.out(26237): sDestination: 
    07-30 23:12:50.291: I/System.out(26237): sStart: qwert
    07-30 23:12:50.526: D/AndroidRuntime(26237): Shutting down VM
    07-30 23:12:50.531: W/dalvikvm(26237): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c4a930)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17360)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    ... 11 more
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at com.example.otpxmlgetter.ReverseGeocode.getCoordinatesFromString(ReverseGeocode.java:33)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    at com.example.otpxmlgetter.MainActivity.planTrip(MainActivity.java:136)
    07-30 23:12:50.566: E/AndroidRuntime(26237):    ... 14 more
    07-30 23:17:50.721: I/Process(26237): Sending signal. PID: 26237 SIG: 9
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Address address = addressList.get(0);
```

is your problem. if the location is non-existent the addressList will be empty, so you get an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` when trying to access the first listItem.

simply check if your list has items:

```
if(addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
    // location exists
    Address address = addressList.get(0);
    System.out.println(address);
    if(address.hasLatitude() && address.hasLongitude()){
        coordinates[0] = address.getLatitude();
        coordinates[1] = address.getLongitude();
        this.canGetCoordinates = true;
        this.isLocationValid = true;
        System.out.println(coordinates[0]);
        System.out.println(coordinates[1]);
    }
} else { 
    // location does not exist
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! Doesn't seem to have any side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can always catch this IllegalStateException. If method doesn't declare to throw it, then catch Exception and check if it's an instance of IllegalStateException. Otherwise, rethrow the exception.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you please add an example, I can't really follow the instructions.